# Drush and multisite config

Tags: drush, multi-sites

I have a new multisite instance with the [Backup & Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module installed in `/sites/all/modules/`

When I run `drush` the `bam-*` commands don't show as available commands.

I have site aliases set up and if I run `drush @site-alias bam-destinations` as a test it does show the available backup destinations.

Is there a more correct way to show the list of available commands for all sites as well as site-specific commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try `drush @site help`?  Simply running `drush help` will show only the globally-available commands; you must change your working directory to the folder with your settings.php file or use a site alias to select a specific site to see the help for drush commands defined in that site's module.

Sometimes, the Drush command cache can get in your way.  Run `drush cc drush` to reset it.  Since `drush @site bam-destinations` is working, this is probably not your issue.

If you are still having trouble after trying these things, also try upgrading to the latest version of Drush (HEAD of master), as some fixes that may be related have been committed post-Drush-5.4.  Also try `drush @site help bam-destinations` and `drush @site bam-destinations --help`.  If you're still having trouble, please post a bug report in the Drush issue queue.

Comment: Damn, of course, I completely forgot about the 'help' argument. D'oh

Comment: You're not the first one.  See http://drupal.org/node/1016456